# Поочередное выполнение javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Доброго времени суток.
Есть страница, HTML, к ней подключил 3 javascript файла:

```html
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/1file.js" defer></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/2file.js" defer></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/3file.js" defer></script>
 
</head>
```

Проблема в том, что js файлы загружаются и выполняются одновременно. 
А мне нужно, что бы они   строго последовательно выполнялись, т.к иначе они мешают друг другу, и нарушают работу.
Я конечно мог бы вставить `.setTimeout()` но поскольку в скриптах я использую jquery и подключаюсь к сайту, все зависит от пинга и компьютера. А т.е определенное значение пауз я задать не могу.
Как мне сделать, что бы следующий скрипт не начинал загружаться, пока не выполнится предыдущий?

Comment: Что подразумеваете под этим: 'что бы следующий скрипт не начинал загружаться, пока не выполнится предыдущий' - это значит пока он не **загрузиться** или все же пока не **выполнится**?

Comment: да, мне нужно что бы они выполнялись по очереди, не верно сформулировал.

Comment: не понятен вопрос. На данный момент у вас в коде у скриптов стоит defer, из-за чего они и грузятся хаотично (хотя выполняться должны последовательно). Уберите этот аттрибут и скрипты будут загружаться и выполняться строго последовательно. По-умолчанию скрипты (как и все другие файлы) обрабатываются именно так..

Answer (score 3):

Используйте defer ([подробнее](http://learn.javascript.ru/external-script)):

```
<script src="1.js" defer></script>
<script src="2.js" defer></script>
```

Comment: пробовал - не помогло =(

Comment: @Black_Dog если эти файлы используют jQuery, то они могут загрузиться раньше её и соответственно работать не станут.

Comment: т.е проблема не решаема?

Comment: А что вы jQuery defer не проставили?

Comment: @AleksanderK. не видел смысла его к библиотеке ставить, поставил - не помогло..

Comment: @Black_Dog если jquery ставили и не помогло, то осмелюсь усомниться в методах проверки результата. Как вы определяете последовательно выполняются скрипты или нет?

Comment: `defer` всего лишь указывает, что данный скрипт должен загрузиться после загрузки документа. Но это никак не влияет на _**порядок**_ загрузки скриптов.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно обернуть содержимое которое необходимо выполнить в функции и передавать им колбеки, которые вызывать в конце - когда вы заканчиваете работу этого скрипта. Например.

```
//1.js
function s1(onComptele) {
  //... <-- ваш код
  onComplete(); // когда все закончили вызовем
}

//2.js
function s2(onComptele) {
  //... <-- ваш код
  onComplete(); // когда все закончили вызовем
}

//3.js
function s3(onComptele) {
  //... <-- ваш код
  onComplete(); // когда все закончили вызовем
}

//app.js - объеденяет все содержимое
s1(function() {
  s2(function() {
    s3();
  });
});
```

Также можете посмотреть в сторону [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise), они избавят вас от callback hell и выглядеть будет так:

```
s1().then(function() {
  return s2();
)).then(function() {
  return s3();
));
```

Для этого нужно использовать такой подход:

```
//n.js
function sN() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // ... <- ваш код
    resolve(); // когда все выполнится
    // или reject(error) - если хотите показать что была ошибка
  });
}
```

Но не забудьте что для поддержки промисов всеми браузерами придется использовать библиотеку-полифил% [promise-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) или [ES6-Promise](https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise).